# Cannot install ubuntu budgie themes 18.04

Tags: themes, ubuntu-budgie

I'm a linux noob. I chose Ubuntu budgie 18.04. I installed it on my laptop to test it out and it works wonders. I can change my themes and all that. I installed in on my computer too to use it as a daily driver. After doing some updates I noticed that I get an error whenever I try to install a theme from Budgie Themes and Layouts. Are there updates that I didn't do that allow theme installations? If so, can I get a list of updates/installs that I have to put in linux in order for theme installations to work?

For reference, the error I get says "Failed installation of material-materia2-theme". Doesn't help much but I thought I'd put this in.

Comment: This same question was asked on the Budgie forum, and got an answer. It turned out to be a missing signing key for the repository.
https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/cannot-install-ubuntu-budgie-themes-18-04/3301